# Incorrectly specifing a fixed effect as a random effect in LMM

Tags: mixed-model

In my area of research, psycholinguistics, it is common to analyze the data using LMM where both subjects and items (words) are treated as crossed random effects.  However, the items that we use in our experiments are in no way really selected at random.  Because we have to control for so many variables while manipulating the variable of interest (the fixed effect), the final set of words may well be the population of words.  Said another way, if I wanted to try and replicate my experiment there would not be another set of words available.  My question is what effect does putting items as a random effect in an LMM have on the power and validity of the model (particularly the parameter estimates for the fixed effects) when we can't really assume that items is a random effect.

Comment: I have still not figured out or been able to find the answer to this question.  Any info pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You really needs to give more details of the experiment for this to be answerable. In particular, what is the hypothesis of interest? If it is about particular words, random effects is maybe not correct. Otherwise, there is many conflicting interpretations/definitions of re in use ... and no agreement.